# How does one insert a new line in a cell in a Google doc spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I saw a question with this earlier but nobody seems to have it answered in a way that helps me.

I need to paste text into a Google Docs spreadsheet cell but it needs to have two new lines in it. Whenever I paste it in, it puts the two new lines in three different cells. If I paste it into the one cell by going into the mode to edit that cell, the cell just shows up blank, as it does when I press <kbd>Command</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to create a new line. Having any more than one line of text in a Google docs spreadsheet seems to be making a cell show up blank.

How do I fix this and get multiple lines?

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl + enter?

Answer (score 3):

What are you using to paste the text?

I did the following:

1. In Notepad, I created some dummy text with newlines in it

```
This is some test text


with newlines
```

2. I copied it from Notepad (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)

3. In a Google Spreadsheet, I selected a cell and pressed <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter edit mode

4. I pasted the text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) in the cell and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>

The text appears in the cell with the newlines included.

Further, I edited some other cells, and both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> added newlines.

(Windows 7, Firefox 17.0)

Answer (score 0):

If you enter the text by just clicking on the cell and pasting, it will put it in 3 different cells, just as you have described.

If you enter the text by clicking on the cell and then clicking on the editing line (top of the worksheet to the right of the "fx") it will do as you expect. It puts all the text in the same cell.

Answer (score 0):

Or a better option is just to press control enter and it doesn't make the browser close down and it doesn't make the browser huge. It simply just adds another line to the cell allowing you to put more than one line in a cell.